# Clojure : parse a XML, remove head and tail lines first

Tags: java, clojure, text-processing

I come today with a problem I cannot solve.

**Context**

I have a catalog with this kind of input :

```
<catalogue>
  <produit>
    <nom>mince</nom>
    <sku>25</sku>
    <criterias>
      <criteria>65</criteria>
      <criteria>25</criteria>
    </criterias>
  </produit>
  <produit>
    <nom>gros</nom>
    <sku>56</sku>
    <criterias>
      <criteria>35</criteria>
      <criteria>8</criteria>
    </criterias>
  </produit>
</catalogue>
```

I want to transform it as EDN. In fact I succeed with sample data; This is the first step (then I do only lazy processing) :

```
(defn catalog-fr-to-edn []
  (let [content (slurp "catalog-fr.xml")]
    (->> (xml/parse-str content)
         (into {}))))
```

But, as you can see - maybe I miss something - but I do not see other way to parse an XML from this library apart from slurping all the content as STR. The problem is that I have 700 mb of data !

So I tought about something better

1) First remove the "catalogue" lines

```
  <produit>
    <nom>mince</nom>
    <sku>25</sku>
    <criterias>
      <criteria>65</criteria>
      <criteria>25</criteria>
    </criterias>
  </produit>
  <produit>
    <nom>gros</nom>
    <sku>56</sku>
    <criterias>
      <criteria>35</criteria>
      <criteria>8</criteria>
    </criterias>
  </produit>
```

So that I have virtually N XML "files" that correspond to N products.

2) Write records line by line like

{:sku 25 ...}

**Problem**

I think the first step is ok (I did not see the tail of the file, the header is ok).He is the script for this first part

```
(defn remove-lines [input nskip]
  (let [path (->> (decompose-filepath input)
                  (last)
                  (str "qsdqsdqsdqsd."))]
    (with-open [rdr (io/reader input)]
      (with-open [wrt (io/writer path)]
        (loop [n nskip]
          (let [line (.readLine rdr)]
            (cond (nil? line)
                    nil
                  (and (not (nil? line)) (not (empty? (re-find #"<\\catalogue>.*" line))))
                    nil
                  :else
                    (cond (pos? n)
                            (recur (dec n))
                          :else
                            (do (doto wrt (.write line) (.newLine))
                                          (recur n))))))))
    (io/delete-file input)
    (rename-file path input)))
```

Now I want to do the second step but I have no clue of how to do it. I could do this for 1 product but I don't know how to have something ion the file that save position in it.

The XML parsing is ok so let's say I just want lines like that as output (I removes the newlines for visibility) :

```
"<produit><nom>mince</nom><sku>25</sku><criterias><criteria>65</criteria><criteria>25</criteria></criterias></produit>"
```

i.e. read the content until  is reached, take the read article, writes it and then jump to the next article.

Do I need other Java classes ? I can uwork with Java code if it's better.

Or maybe I miss something from `clojure.data.xml` library ?

Thanks

Comment: (clojure.data.xml/parse (io/input-stream (io/file "catalog-fr.xml"))) should be enough. clojure.data.xml/parse returns lazy-tree of element records

Comment: Thanks, in fact I had a problem with my write function but parse is better. I wrote a java function to achieve what I want but it's useless at the end ! Everything is ok now.

Comment: @JosephYourine If you’ve solved the problem, please don’t forget to answer this question yourself (or simply delete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit naïve and it is Java code but it is easily portable to Clojure. I did not tried it intensively since I do not need it

package file;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CatalogReader {

    public static void processFile (String input, String output) throws FileNotFoundException {

        try {

            // File input
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input);   
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));

            //File output
            File out = new File(output);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

            String line;
            String product = "";

            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("</catalogue>");
            Matcher mat;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                mat = pat.matcher(line);

                while (!mat.find()) {

                    product.concat(line);

                }

                bw.write(product);
                bw.newLine()
                product = "";

            }

            br.close();
            bw.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) { System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}
    }

}
```